# How to find JavaScript code that is waiting on promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asynchronous, promise

We have a rather complex asynchronous system in JavaScript. All functions in the JavaScript library are designed to be asynchronous. We mainly use the AngularJS deferred objects and some parts use the jQuery (we don't intermingle them though - i.e. Angular code waits on Angular deferred promises).

The problem that we are coming across is that the code appears to "hang" on start-up, 2 out of 5 times. There looks like there is a problem when the JS code is cached and the timing of the promise resolutions.

There doesn't seem to be any tools or anything that can point to what the offending code is waiting on when a hang occurs.

How do you find JavaScript code that is waiting on a promise?

Thanks.

Comment: Just dropping this: https://github.com/tildeio/ember-extension/pull/76 It's still WIP, but it should be usable. That said, you could also debug the library code.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine this extension is for Amber, while the OP is referring to the AngularJS and jQuery implementations. Am I missing something?

Comment: @EliranMalka it's for promises. It's done by Ember's developers, but it's generic to promises.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine(you could also debug the library code) - my problem at the moment is that I don't know how to, and don't know any tools that can help. Outside putting console debug everywhere that will influence timing. The Ember App says: "This is not an Ember application."

Comment: @FlorianMargaine, I spoke too soon - using that extension it's not possible to debug *anything* unless it's an Amber project, so it's not very helpful (much to my dismay, I'd love to use that with my Angular projects).

Comment: @EliranMalka damn! The tool is definitely going to be reused in a more generic way though, just not yet :(

Comment: @user626201 using the debugger of Chrome Dev Tools?

Comment: By "waiting" and "hang" you mean that the promise does not (never?) resolve?

Comment: @FlorianMargaine - yes, in the Chrome dev inspector

Comment: @Bergi - yes - the whole system appears to just stop. We expect certain functions to occur, but they never do. We have yet to be able to trace all the way backwards to find what is preventing the system, nor the offending promise that is not resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the error actually ended up being not related to promises but timing of dependency loading. We are using LAB.js as the file loader. LAB.js supports a "chain" loading mechanism of JavaScript dependencies.

What was happening is that there were 2 chains that we had not released were related to each other. Both chains where being loaded asynchronously and thus, at the point of running the JavaScript files, there was an opportunity to attempt use an object that was not loaded.

What compounded the issue was the Angular.js 1.2.13 failed quietly in this scenario. An exception occurred during the loading of Angular services and the exception never propagated to higher level code nor was there any debug to say it had hit an exception:

```
function getService(serviceName) {
  if (cache.hasOwnProperty(serviceName)) {
    if (cache[serviceName] === INSTANTIATING) {
      throw $injectorMinErr('cdep', 'Circular dependency found: {0}', path.join(' <- '));
    }
    return cache[serviceName];
  } else {
    try {
      path.unshift(serviceName);
      cache[serviceName] = INSTANTIATING;
      return cache[serviceName] = factory(serviceName);
    } catch (err) {
      if (cache[serviceName] === INSTANTIATING) {
        delete cache[serviceName];
      }
      throw err;
    } finally {
      path.shift();
    }
  }
}
```

The `throw err` above did not get through to the browser and was caught somewhere in the system and "ignored".

Once we had found the exception, it was quite easy to track the chain loading issue.